# Как предотвратить submit?

Tags: jquery

Делаю аякс-проверку на сервере, не важно что там происходит, ответ либо "0" либо "1", при "0" форма не должна сабмититься, мой код таков:

```
$('form[name=gform]').submit(function(){

    guest =$('#guest').val();

    $.ajax({

        url: "do.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: { action: 'guest', guest: guest },
        success: function(data) {

            if (data==0)
            {

                return false;

            }

        }

    });

});
```

к сожалению сабмит происходит в любом случае, как предотвратить это?
Как видите меня ***return false*** не спасло.

Comment: Вы сами поняли что написали? Как Вы получите ответ сервера без сабмита? 0 - он же тоже должен прийти с сервера...

Вообще копайте в другую сторону.

Comment: я получаю (КОРРЕКТНЫЙ) ответ с сервера. Вопрос в том только что форма-таки сабмитится при return false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

попробуйте:

```
$('form[name=gform]').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

или

```
    ...
    $.ajax({...});
    return false;
});
```

т.к. вы не совсем понимаете по какому принципу работает колбэк `success`

Comment: да, я убрал вообще submit, не правильно подошел к ситуации, пришлось немного логику переделать, ну кто не ошибается?